# IDE to use for Python for Quant Trading

Tags: programming, quant-trading-strategies, trading, algorithmic-trading, asset-pricing

Dear Quantitative Finance Stack Community,

Since many Quantitative propietary trading firms seem to be using Python over alternatives such as STATA. I have now decided to get myself familiar with Python as well. Since I want to be able to write and edit scripts in an efficient and reliable way in Python, I was wondering what IDE (integrated development environment) people in this community prefer to use and why, when it comes to developing trading strategies, analyzing financial data and other related applications.

I'll gladly hear from you,
Kind regards, Julien Maas.

Comment: This is fairly subjective but I'd expect a majority of people to use either VS Code or PyCharm. I prefer the former because it's free and features lots of extensions. It also supports other languages.

Comment: partial to Pycharm over here, community edition is free

Comment: PyCharm, I like the Database integration, and profiling tools in the pro version.